# Join two tables with max aggregation on one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables:

**Material**:

```
ID
```

**Price**:

```
BookPrice
PriceDate
MaterialID
```

I want to get all materials and their last price (price row with most recent `PriceDate`).

I am using SQL Server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post up what you have tried so we can tell you where you have gone wrong.

Comment: Can you please show us the query you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT c.ID, d.BookPrice, d.PriceDate 
FROM Material as c
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MaterialID, BookPrice, PriceDate 
     FROM Price as a
     WHERE PriceDate = 
          (SELECT MAX(PriceDate) 
           FROM Price as b 
           WHERE a.MaterialID = b.MaterialID
          )
    ) as d 
ON c.ID = d.MaterialID
```

See the [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee7cd0/21/0) to investigate further if needed.

Comment: Thank You @Trippino. it worked.
Here is the simpler approach:

SELECT        a.MaterialID, a.BookPrice, a.PriceDate, Material.Name
FROM            Price AS a INNER JOIN
                         Material ON a.MaterialID = Material.Name
WHERE        (a.PriceDate =
                             (SELECT        MAX(PriceDate) AS Expr1
                               FROM            Price AS b
                               WHERE        (a.MaterialID = MaterialID)))

Answer (score 1):

Use [outer apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for that:

```
select M.ID, P.BookPrice
from Material as M
    outer apply (
        select top 1 P.BookPrice
        from Price as P
        where P.MaterialID = M.ID
        order by P.PriceDate desc
    ) as P
```

you can also use [row_number()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), but it's usually slower that outer apply approach:

```
with cte as (
    select
        M.ID, P.BookPrice,
        row_number() over(partition by M.ID order by P.PriceDate) as row_num
    from Material as M
        left outer join Price as P on P.MaterialID = M.ID
)
select
    c.ID, c.BookPrice
from cte as c
where c.row_num = 1
```

Comment: Outer apply dose the mission.
but at first time show the following error:
The OUTER APPLY SQL construct or statement is not supported.